# Find Unique Element in two List<String>

Tags: apex

I'm trying to find the unique element in two list of string, i have tried in this way

```
 public boolean findtheSameElement( ){
    List <String> list1 = new List<String>{'a','b','c'};
    List <String> list2 = new List<String>{'d','e','a'};
    String listElement1;
    String listElement2;

    for(integer i=0; i<list1.size();i++){

        listElement1= list1.get(i);

        for(integer n=i+1; i<list2.size();i++){
            elementoLista2 = list2.get(i);
          if(listElement1== listElement2){
               System.debug(listElement2);
            return true;
          }


        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use `Set` for de-duplication.

Comment: @amiga 500

can you please tell what is the desired output of listElement1 and ListElement2 ?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but there could be two answers depending on the circumstances:

1. You simply want a list of all unique values

   ```
   List <String> list1 = new List<String>{'a','b','c'};
   List <String> list2 = new List<String>{'d','e','a'};

   Set<String> uniqueValues = new Set<String>(list1);
   uniqueValues.addAll(list2);

   return uniqueValues;
   ```

Answer: Use a set, values are always unique.

2. You are just trying to find the element in List 2 that is the first match from an element is list 1

   ```
   List <String> list1 = new List<String>{'a','b','c'};
   List <String> list2 = new List<String>{'d','e','a'};

   Set<String> tmp = New Set<String>(list2);

   for(String s1 : list1){
       if(tmp.contains(s1))
           return s1;
    }
   ```

Convert the second list to a set and then use `Contains` and return the first match. this is what you are doing in your code so it may be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can find all of the duplicates using the retainAll method; this also allows you to quickly find the duplicates if you wanted to:

```
public Boolean do2ListsContainsDuplicates(String[] list1, String[] list2) {
    // Convert lists to sets
    Set<String> set1 = new Set<String>(list1), set2 = new Set<String>(list2);
    // Modify set1 to contain only values also in set2.
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    // If not empty, there were duplicates
    return !set1.isEmpty();
}

public String[] getDuplicatesFrom2Lists(String[] list1, String[] list2) {
    // Convert lists to sets
    Set<String> set1 = new Set<String>(list1), set2 = new Set<String>(list2);
    // Modify set1 to contain only values also in set2.
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    // Convert back to a list
    return new List<String>(set1);
}
```