# How to separate only duplicated elements in apex List?

Tags: apex, list

I have a List with objects and some of them are duplicated.

I need a new list containing only the duplicated elements but each element must be available only once.

For instance:
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6}
In this List I need the returned result to be:
{1, 2, 5}

How can that be achieved in apex without nested loops?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without loops. There are surely dozens of ways to go about it, but here's one such:

```
public List<Integer> getDuplicates(List<Integer> input)
{
    Set<Integer> output = new Set<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> alreadySeen = new Set<Integer>();
    for (Integer value : input)
    {
        if (alreadySeen.contains(value))
            output.add(value);
        alreadySeen.add(value);
    }
    return new List<Integer>(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I had in mind but now I need all occurrences of the duplicated elements but without the first one. Example: {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6} `Result:` {1, 1, 1, 2, 5}

Comment: Another example: {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7} `Result:` {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7}

Comment: @lemdev This is different than what your question states. If we follow your example here, the result of your original example ought to be `{1,1,1,2,5}`, no? At any rate, this is a good example of when it's appropriate to edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: @lemdev Actually, now that I think about it, I'm not sure that you should edit your question. I guess that this instead shows the value of stating your true goal upfront, and explaining what you're doing that needs such an odd (to me) filtering of your data. This is getting close to X-Y problem territory.

Comment: Yeah what you are asking in the comments here is *completely different* than what you asked in your question. Hence my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a set and back again. Fortunately, there's a constructor that does this, so here's a simple format you can use:

```
Integer[] deDups = 
  new List<Integer>(
    new Set<Integer>(origList)
  );
```

The line breaks are for legibility, but you can also consider this a one-liner if you prefer.

Comment: Doesn’t this also leave 3 and 4 present? Your answer here may be more relevant: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138495/find-unique-element-in-two-liststring/138502?r=SearchResults#138502

Comment: @Eric gah, I  misread the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: NP. I was trying to find your answer to a similar question when you posted. I know you have answered this before but not sure if the one I found was it

Comment: @Eric Actually, no, I think I'm right: this code finds all the duplicates, but only once. That one isn't this one. I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track, at least.